# Can I bind a textblock's content to only part of a string in an observable collection?

Tags: wpf, string, binding, path, observablecollection

I'm relatively new to WPF so apologies if there is an obvious or simple answer to this that I am not seeing.

I have an ObservableCollection of items with several different sized images for each.
The relative path for each image is in string format, with image files stored in different subfolders.

The image paths are in the format:

```
imagepath = @"subfolder/subfolder/filename.png"
```

I would like to be able to bind to a textblock but show only the filename below each image without changing the image path. Is this possible? I gather it would require a converter of some sort, but I have been struggling with it as I cannot find a reasonable way of showing only part of a string.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

To clarify, my 'value' is non-static, referencing items in an observable collection eg.

```
ObservableCollection<Icon> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

items.Add(new Item{imagename = "someimagename",
imagepath= "somefolder/somesubfolder/somefilename.png"}) etc...
```

I'm only starting to get to grips with 'getting' values from my collection. Any help with filling in the 'value.Tostring()' part to get dynamic values for item.imagepath would be really appreciated so I can get this working.

I've currently been trying along these lines:

```
class getFilenameFromPathConverter : IValueConverter
 {     
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)

      {    Item item = value as Item; 
           PropertyInfo info = value.GetType().GetProperty("imagepath");
           string filename = info.GetValue(item, null).ToString();
           return System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename); } 

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
       {
          throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
   }
```

But I'm getting an Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thanks

Comment: I get "An object reference is requried for the non-static field, method, or property ..." That's presuming you mean doing:

 `return System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.imagepath.ToString());`

Comment: @Chris Can you paste here your Textbox "Text" binding expression (XAML)?

Comment: Ok follow these instructions
1) Place a breakpoint on your converter's "convert" method.
2) When the breakpoint hits check the "value" parameter that is being passed. If the "value" parameter equals your file path then good. If not let me know.
3) If step 2 passes then empty your convert method and add only the following line: 

return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(value.ToString());

Give it a try.

Comment: This has nothing to with your 'value' being static or non-static..that does not matter

Comment: @Chris : Look, You don't need to do that in WPF converters. The parameter 'value' does not need to be converted to Item meaning there is no need for :
Item item = value as Item; 
string filename = item.imagepath.ToString();

Just paste the following in your converter character by character (Just copy/paste ) and you will be fine :).

return System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(value.ToString());

Comment: The parameter "value" is already your imagePath...You are receiving an exception because you are trying to parse it to item which is wrong...
As I said before your converter should only contain the following line

return System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(value.ToString());

Comment: That worked perfectly after sorting out a few errors i had made elsewhere - and made complete sense thinking about it, with the value coming from the existing binding. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML as specified by fatty.

Your converter should look like:

```
class getFilenameFromPathConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Path.GetFileName(value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a big step in the right direction, although I found that I need GetFileNameWithoutExtension instead of just GetFileName.

However, my 'value' is non-static, referencing items in an observable collection (please see Edit)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enlist the help of a [converter](http://www.google.com/search?q=wpf%20converter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) to get this value.

Create a class that implements IValueConverter, and in the Convert method return the part of the string that you want to display.

In your TextBlock, you bind to the property like `{Binding Path=imagepath, Converter={StaticResource getFilenameFromPathConverter}}`

Comment: Thanks, yeah I figured as much - good to have the XAML but really I'm struggling with the Converter (see edit) but gettign close thanks to @Zahid